# always return false in try/catch using cypress in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

what is standard way to send out value from `then`? I have following code, that function always return `false`, even though I debug in `then` `isExist` variable is true at the moment. I assume it is related to something async/sync issue but I do not know what the stand way to use try catch and return value in function

```
function isExist(selector: string): boolean{
  let isExist =false
  try {
    cy.xpath(`count(//*[@class="${selector}"])`).then((count) => {
      isExist = !!count;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    cy.log(`${selector} is not found`);
  }
  return isExist;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `try/catch`? Instead put it inside the `then`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: i have to use `try/catch` as selector is not guarantee to be valid

Comment: @jacobcan118 that's not true. `try/catch` doesn't work with "default" promises. You'll need to use `async/await`.

Comment: the reason I have to use `try/catch` is because `cy.xpath(`count(//*[@class="${selector}"])`)` that I need to handle the situation of selector is invalid

Comment: @jacobcan118 if `cy.xpath` is a promise, then `try/catch` won't work. Use `.catch` instead?

Comment: possible to how me the example code to use `catch`? i have cy.xapth().then((count ) => {}).catch() but the error still log

Comment: Try replacing `});` with `}).catch(error => cy.log(\`${selector} is not found\`))`?

Comment: hm...i have the error that catch isnot chainable ```cy.xpath(`count(//*[@class="${selector}"])`).then((count) => {
      isExist = !!count;}).catch(error => cy.log('error'))```

Comment: @jacobcan118 then I'm likely mistaken thinking that `cy.xpath` is a promise. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the Promise in order to use try/catch. Here's an example of how to use try/catch for error handling of a resolved or rejected `Promise` - both cases return a value:

```js
function isExist() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      rand <= 5 ? resolve(rand) : reject(rand);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function main() {
  console.log('Waiting');
  try {
    const exist = await isExist();

    console.log(`Checked for existence successfully: ${exist}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`An error occurred while checking if exist: ${error}`);
  }

  console.log('Done');
}


main();
```

Comment: `cy.xpath` is likely not a true promise, but might be a "thenable". This doesn't affect your answer however.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the xpath result into a Promise

```js
function doesExist(selector: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    return cy.xpath(`count(//*[@class="${selector}"])`).then(count => resolve(!!count))
  })
}

it('tests an element exists', async () => {

   const exists = await doesExist('my-selector');
   ...

});
```

Try/catch is unnecessary because `xpath('count()')` never fails (it returns 0 if the element is not present).

Reiterating, as noted in your previous question, this approach to Cypress testing is a code smell.

Comment: in my case i have to use `try/catch` to handle the situation like invalid xpath because the selector may be invalid

Comment: No, think about it - if the selector is invalid, `xpath(count())` will just return 0 - it will not throw an error.

Comment: hm...but i have the error when running `Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'count(//*[@class="[class="selector"]"])' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: That's because of too many double quotes, just bad syntax. What are you passing in as `selector`? You only need the class name.

Comment: yap...however that is my use case, I have to handle the invalid selector, sometimes selector parameter is passed in as valid selector already

Comment: So, your message `cy.log('${selector} is not found');` is misleading, it should be `cy.log('${selector} is not valid');`.

Comment: gotcha..so any suggestion how I should handle it?